# Threshold for floating floor on 2x4s

Tags: flooring, threshold

I am renovating my garage to add a bedroom. The flooring is laminate wood / LVT, on top of 1/2" subfloor, on top of 2x4s - for the purpose of keeping the floor off the concrete.

The contractor is having a hard time finding an appropriate threshold to go from concrete to the room as it would need to be about a 2-3" transition.  Would it be better to just accept that there will be a step up into the room and just hide the different layers with some sort of fascia, or are there thresholds for this high of a transition that aren't basically wheelchair ramps?

Comment: I think you'll have problems finding something suitable for a 2-3" transition.  Also, that's an unusual height, so potentially will be a tripping hazard as well.  Is it too late to raise the whole floor height by adding more than just the single 2x4s to underneath your flooring, and be able to easily get the whole floor completely flush with your existing floor level?

Comment: @Milwrdfan eventually, the floor should be the same height.  But for right now, it's an area being walled off, so there will definitely be a step up to get into the room.

Comment: My in-laws have a 2-3" step from their family room to the rest of the house. Hasn't been a big issue any time I've ever been there in the last 30+ years.

Answer (score 2):

Anything that transitions that high will be more of a ramp.  I think you need to decide if you are willing to have a ramp or a step. A step may be more of a trip hazard, but this is your house.

Comment: That's what I was thinking, too.  Unfortunately the subfloor is already laid down and the 2x4 supports have been secured to the concrete, so it's too late to go back and find something not as high.  I'm guessing a small step is the most likely solution, which should be fine since the room is only accessible from the rest of the house via stairs.